Catching syntax error when trying to write to and call an alias in .bashrc
I'm trying to create an alias for determining whether or not I need to reboot my server.
Here's what I'm doing:
$ echo "alias rcr='if [ -f /var/run/reboot-required ]; then read -p \"Continue? (Y/N): \" confirm && [[ $confirm == [yY] || $confirm == [yY][eE][sS] ]] || exit 1 && reboot; else echo No reboot needed; fi'" >> ~/.bashrc
$ source ~/.bashrc
$ rcr

But this throws an error:
bash: conditional binary operator expected
bash: syntax error near `[yY]'

I've tried every different combination that I could think of, from escaping characters to prefixing variables. I'm a little new to bash (not Linux in general), so I'm just trying to get the hang of this.
What am I doing wrong here? Here's what gets added to .bashrc:
alias rcr='if [ -f /var/run/reboot-required ]; then read -p "Continue? (Y/N): " confirm && [[  == [yY] ||  == [yY][eE][sS] ]] || exit 1 && reboot; else echo No reboot needed; fi'


Does the [[  == [yY] ||  == [yY][eE][sS] ]] that gets added match what you're trying to add?

As far as I can gather, yes. I'm trying to add this bit

You should be checking /var/run/reboot*. There are more flag files in use than just reboot-required.

The outer double quotes allow your interactive shell to expand $confirm - presumably to an empty value - so that what you actually write to the .bashrc file is
alias rcr='if [ -f /var/run/reboot-required ]; then read -p "Continue? (Y/N): " confirm && [[  == [yY] ||  == [yY][eE][sS] ]] || exit 1 && reboot; else echo No reboot needed; fi'

You can prevent that by escaping the $ (which is an an additional form of quoting):
$ echo "alias rcr='if [ -f /var/run/reboot-required ]; then read -p \"Continue? (Y/N): \" confirm && [[ \$confirm == [yY] || \$confirm == [yY][eE][sS] ]] || exit 1 && reboot; else echo No reboot needed; fi'"
alias rcr='if [ -f /var/run/reboot-required ]; then read -p "Continue? (Y/N): " confirm && [[ $confirm == [yY] || $confirm == [yY][eE][sS] ]] || exit 1 && reboot; else echo No reboot needed; fi'

However IMHO it would be simpler and clearer to use a quoted here document to prevent expansion altogether:
cat >> ~/.bashrc << 'EOF'

alias rcr='
  if [ -f /var/run/reboot-required ]; then 
    read -p "Continue? (Y/N): " confirm
    case $confirm in 
      ([yY]|[yY][eE][sS]) reboot ;; 
    esac
  else
    echo "No reboot needed"
  fi
'
EOF

I also took the liberty of converting your conditionals to a case statement. You could also consider using a shell function instead of an alias here.
